# git rebase --continue vs. new commit

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase, git-commit, merge-conflict-resolution

If I run into merge errors, I usually solve the merge errors, add my files again and use 
`git rebase --continue`
to continue with pulling and pushing.

Now I had some time to take a deeper look into how git works and figured out, that it should be possible to create a new commit instead. I think, thats maybe a good idea to clarify that there were some merge errors and that they were solved manually.

So which one is recommed to use and what are their both advantages and disadvantages?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `git rebase --continue`. Resolving conflicts is an expected part of rebasing. You're throwing away the old commit that actually caused the conflict, so I don't see any benefit in recording its resolution separately.

Comment: Using `git commit` seems to do the same thing as `git rebase --continue`, but it runs the pre-commit hook. Is there a good reason not to use `git commit`?

Answer (score 0):

To add to the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41378972/149998), your two options are rebase and merge.

Rebase is good when you're working alone on a feature, or specifically need to be replaying your changes ontop of the latest master.

Merge is good when you're working with other people, as rebasing rewrites the history and makes that collaboration difficult or downright impossible.

A quick rebase (`git pull --rebase`) is also handy if your changes are frequently pushed (as are those of other people) and you want to ensure your git history is cleaner and easier to follow in visual tools such as `gitg` or the `git log --graph` view.